# Adobe After Effects Script: Use chroma key filter on layer

Tags: scripting, effects, extendscript, after-effects

I am currently scripting for After Effects using ExtendScript Toolkit

How do I apply the chroma key filter to a layer / composition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use a standalone solution to make this as it is not included directly in After Effects